# How to select modules in Google Guice based on a factor

Tags: guice

I have a application which works in two different geographies: say US and EU(Europe). My injection depends on this Geo. I want two write two different Modules for the respective Geo and one common module to be use by both Geos. I was able to accomplish this in Spring application by using Profile annotation but I am not able to find any straight forward way to do this except using if-else while adding modules to Injector. Is there any cleaner or other conventional way to achieve this in Google Guice?

Comment: did you think about using Providers for beans which will have different implementation depends on this Geo parameter? Then you can return US/EU instance of specific class when its needed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether yours is a build-time concern or a run/time one.

With the former you'd want a single geo module to be in the classpath (plus the common). To achieve this I would look into your build system capabilities (e.g. Maven profiles) to add the correct source tree for the desired geo at compile time perhaps.

With the latter (run-time) you may want to use factories to create the geo-specific dependencies maybe based on a map binder whose keys may be Locales and values could be the implementation for the specific geo.